# Conferência de Diagrama de Classes de Consultório Médico

Tags: uml, diagrama-de-classes, multiplicidade

Com base no mini-mundo abaixo foi modelado um Diagrama de Classes no Astah Community (versão free com menos *features* que a professional para uso não-comercial: http://astah.net/editions/community - Antigamente este programa tinha o nome de JUDE)

> **Mini-mundo / Cenário**:
>
> O gerenciamento de informações de pacientes e de marcações de consultas é essencial para a organização de processos em clínicas e consultórios. Muitos destes ainda não contam com a automatização necessária para que a marcação de consultas e acesso a prontuários se torne eficiente, o que gera problemas para atendentes, médicos e para quem precisa de atendimento. Dessa forma se faz necessário um sistema que seja capaz de agilizar e gerenciar os agendamentos de consultas, assim como o acesso aos prontuários.
>
> Objetivo:
>   Desenvolver um sistema genérico de Agendamento de Consultas para Consultórios e Clínicas que compartilham atendentes, sendo o foco principal o agendamento das consultas e um foco secundário o acesso do paciente aos prontuários de forma online.
>
> Funcionalidades que o sistema deverá possuir:
>
> - Cadastro de Atendentes, Médicos, Especialidades, Pacientes e Convênios.
> - Agendamento de consultas.
> - Divulgação de resultados de exames e prontuários on-line.
> - Disponível ao atendente: Funções de cadastramento e agendamento das consultas.
> - Disponível ao médico: Acesso às consultas marcadas para o próprio e prontuários de seus pacientes.
> - Disponível ao paciente: Acesso aos seus prontuários/resultados de exames on-line.

(agradeço aos usuários @Jeferson Almeida e @Randrade pela ideia da inclusão do mini-mundo para facilitar a compreensão do sistema proposto para a modelagem)

**Diagrama de Classes**

[image: Diagrama de Classes UML - Clínica Médica]

A partir desse diagrama, gostaria que fossem verificadas se podem ser deduzidas as seguintes leituras:

---

Na relação **Atendente X Consulta**:

- 1 atendente agenda 0 ou mais consultas.
- 1 consulta é agendada por 1 atendente.

---

Na relação **Convênio X Paciente**:

- 1 convênio possui 0 ou mais clientes(pacientes) relacionados.
- 1 paciente possui ou não 1 ou mais convênios. ( agradeço à observação do @Jeferson Almeida )

---

Na relação **Convênio X Consulta** (Paciente x Consulta x Convenio):

- 1 Convênio cobre um número indeterminado de Consultas
- 1 Consulta é coberta por 0 (consulta particular) ou 1 Convênio ( agradeço à observação do @Bonifazio e ao @Washington da costa )

---

Na relação **Paciente X Consulta**  (Paciente x Consulta x Convenio):

- 1 paciente tem agendadas nenhuma(se acabou de ser incluído) ou várias consultas.
- 1 consulta é agendada para  1 paciente.

---

Na relação **Consulta X Prontuário**:

- 1 consulta terá ao seu fim 1 prontuário (e nenhum enquanto não foi realizada).
- 1 prontuário é originado em 1 consulta.

---

Na relação **Consulta X Médico**:

- 1 Consulta será realizada por 1 Médico.
- 1 Médico pode ter realizado nenhuma (se acabou de ser cadastrado no sistema)  ou várias consultas.

---

Na relação **Prontuário X Médico**:

- 1 Prontuário é elaborado por 1 Médico.
- 1 Médico pode ter elaborado vários Prontuários.

---

Na relação **Especialidade X Médico**:

- 1 Médico possui 1 ou mais Especialidades. (agradeço à observação do @leonardopessoa )
- Vários médicos podem possuir a mesma especialidade.
- Podem existir no sistema Especialidades cadastradas que ainda não tenham vínculo com nenhum médico.

---

Esse Diagrama de Classes está correto? Está tudo Ok?

Caso a modelagem esteja adequada, fica como um exemplo para usuários futuros que tiverem dúvidas em modelagem de Diagramas de Classes da UML. Caso não esteja, por favor evidencie os problemas encontrados!

Qualquer contribuição é bem vinda.
Obrigado.

Comment: Um médico não poderia ter mais de uma especialidade?

Comment: @leonardopessoa Também fiquei nessa dúvida. Eu modelei que não, mas é uma pergunta bem válida. Você está correto. Corrigi no diagrama.

Comment: Acho que faltam locais na web onde se discutam modelagem de certos sistemas, (salvo [dba.stack](http://dba.stackexchange.com/)) +1 pra pergunta

Comment: Pelas relações levantadas, me parece ok.

Comment: Olá Antonio, gostei da pergunta. Porém, senti falta do "mini mundo" ou algo similar. Não tem como ajudarmos com nada sem entender o escopo do problema antes.

Comment: Realmente sem um contexto fica complicado afirmar se está correto ou não, porém eu mudaria uma coisa, eu faria um relacionamento entre Paciente x Consulta x Convenio, do que simplesmente informar que um usuário vai ter somente um convenio, da maneira que eu disse vc tb mantem o histórico de qual convenio ele usou em cada consulta

Comment: Ótima ideia e observações, incluí mini-mundo e o Diagrama foi modificado para o usuário ter mais de um plano de saúde.

Comment: AntonioAlexandre acredito que o que o @JefersonAlmeida comentou sobre um relacionamento `Paciente x Consulta x Convenio` seria criar ainda um `fk_convenio` dentro da tabela consulta, desse modo inclusive, seria fácil fazer uma query pra descobrir quantas consultas de n convenio foram realizadas, sem ser necessário consultar os pacientes

Comment: @Bonifazio Perfeito. Acrescentada a relação de Convenio com Consulta.

Comment: Essa questão de modelo lógico costuma ser bem subjetiva. Vai depender dos requisitos do sistema alvo. O que você descreveu por extenso de fato está descrito pelos diagramas, muito bom. Só não sei se tem como dar uma resposta pra essa pergunta sem subjetividade.

Comment: Perfeito @GiulianaBezerra, obrigado. Alguns comentários que foram feitos aqui se tivessem sido feitos como resposta, embora não sendo uma análise completa iria dar pontos de reputação pela ajuda. Sei que fica difícil opinar em todos os pontos, mas algo do tipo "Ok, está certo" como se fosse uma correção já ajuda. 3 pessoas votaram para fechar esse tópico devido ao fato da subjetividade, mas acredito que a modelagem é parte importante do processo de desenvolvimento de sistemas e perguntas desse tipo podem ser relevantes para o site e ajudar não só a mim, mas tb a muita gente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essas são minhas considerações, destacadas em negrito.

Na relação Convênio X Paciente:

•   1 convênio possui 0 ou mais clientes(pacientes) relacionados. **(tecnicamente se diz 0 ou N clientes)**

•   1 paciente possui ou não 1 ou mais convênios. ( agradeço à observação do @Jeferson Almeida )

---

Na relação Convênio X Consulta (Paciente x Consulta x Convenio):

•   1 Convênio cobre um número indeterminado de Consultas **(Ok)**

•   1 Consulta é coberta por 1 Convênio ( agradeço à observação do Bonifazio ) **(Você informa que a consulta pode ser particular, sem convênio, então essa afirmação está errada, e o código do convênio não deveria estar nessa tabela, pois uma consulta possui 0 ou 1 convênios)**

---

Na relação Consulta X Prontuário:

•   1 consulta terá ao seu fim 1 prontuário (e nenhum enquanto não foi realizada). **(Tecnicamente: Uma consulta possui 0 ou 1 prontuário)**

•   1 prontuário é originado em 1 consulta. **(Está implícito)**

---

Na relação Prontuário X Médico:

•   1 Prontuário é elaborado por 1 Médico.

•   1 Médico pode ter elaborado vários Prontuários.

**Este relacionamento depende dos requisitos do sistema. Se sempre o mesmo médico da consulta é o que faz o prontuário esse relacionamento é desnecessário**

---

**O relacionamento PACIENTE x PRONTUÁRIO é desnecesário, pois o paciente do prontuário é sempre o mesmo da consulta.**

Comment: Verdade,  a frase "1 Consulta é coberta por 1 Convênio" não está contemplando a consulta particular. Vou corrigir. (+1)

Comment: Como você está editando seu post original, minha resposta passará a não fazer sentido, não sei como fica isso em relação as regras do site.

Comment: Não se preocupe com isso. Eu adiciono na pergunta que mudei devido a uma observação sua. Além disso tem esses comentários aqui. À propósito, nesse sistema um consultório/clínica possui vários médicos e a pessoa pode se consultar com qualquer um deles. (respondendo a sua penúltima observação)

Comment: mas o médico vinculado na consulta pode ser diferente do médico do prontuário? se for sempre o mesmo, você não precisa replicar o código em duas tabelas.

Comment: Acho que estou entendendo aonde você está querendo chegar, mas não estou visualizando as tabelas ainda, apenas as classes, mas o que você disse faz todo sentido. O médico da consulta tem sim que ser o mesmo médico do prontuário.